# Improving a graph generated by R's "curve" function

Tags: r, plot

I'm using R to plot a few functions over closed intervals. For example, the function f(x) = x/3 + sin(x²) over [-1, 3.5].

```
curve(expr = x/3 + sin(x^2), xlim = c(-1, 3.5),
      col = "red", xlab = "x", ylab = "f(x)", main = "Gráfico de f1 sobre [-1, 3.5]")
# gerando uma grade no plot
abline(h = seq(from = -5, to = 5, by = 1), lty = "dotted", col = "lightgray")
abline(v = seq(from = -5, to = 5, by = 1), lty = "dotted", col = "lightgray")

# marcando os eixos x e y
abline(h = 0, lwd = 2)
abline(v = 0, lwd = 2)
```

This is what the graph of f looks like. Now, notice that the line itself is sort of too thin, in general you could say it doesn't look great. I was wondering if there's some way to improve on that, perhaps by making the plot line thicker.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: Add argument `lwd=2`.